# Spring KeycloakOIDCFilter filter invalidate session when account is logout from other applications

Tags: spring, keycloak, wicket

My spring (wicket) application (`ApplicationA`) is using authentication from another application via keycloak filter.
Everything is working perfectly.
When I logout from my application (`ApplicationA`), my other applications (`ApplicationB` and `ApplicationC`) gets logged out also. Both `ApplicationB` and `ApplicationC` are using React Keyloak component that is why they get auto logged out.

However, for `ApplicationA`, it does not use React Keycloak or react. I am just using keycloak servlet filter adapter and keycloak authentication client.

Normally, when I open different pages of `ApplicationA` (In different browser tabs) and I logout of `ApplicationA` in one tab, when I try to reload the other tab or even call another page... it gets redirected to the login page and the session gets invalidated.

**Problem**

My problem with `ApplicationA`, when the account is logout from other applications (either `ApplicationB` or `ApplicationC`)... it does not logout from `ApplicationA`.

It seems that it will just not allow that session to be refreshed, so it will take some time before it gets invalidated.

My target/objective is, when the account is logged out from other application... when I try to open any page or even reload any page in `ApplicationA`... the session gets invalidated and I will be redirected to the login page.

By the way, the login page is from another keycloak application (`AuthenticationApplication`).
During login, it will be redirected to the login page of `AuthenticationApplication`.
After successful authentication, it will redirect me back to the calling application.

So, I am expecting that when the account is logout from either `ApplicationB` or `ApplicationC`... and I call or reload any page from `ApplicationA`... session will end and it will redirect me to the login page of `AuthenticationApplication`.

Currently, I have to be idle for some minutes and when I try to call other page or refresh the page... the session ends and redirects me to the login page of `AuthenticationApplication`.

It would be great if I do not have to wait for some time before the session gets invalid and be redirected to the login page.

**pom.xml changes**

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-servlet-filter-adapter</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-authz-client</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <filter>
      <filter-name>keycloak</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.keycloak.adapters.servlet.KeycloakOIDCFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>keycloak</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

If I want to get the current token, I usually do it this way:

```
    ServletWebRequest request = (ServletWebRequest) RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
    HttpServletRequest containerRequest = request.getContainerRequest();
    m_keycloakSecurityContext = (RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext) containerRequest.getAttribute(KeycloakSecurityContext.class.getName());

    String myToken = null;
    String myEmail = null;
    if (m_keycloakSecurityContext != null) {
        myToken = m_keycloakSecurityContext.getTokenString();
        myEmail = m_keycloakSecurityContext.getToken().getEmail();
    }
```

Even when the account is logout from other application, I noticed that `m_keycloakSecurityContext` still exists and I can still get the token, thus the session is still alive in ApplicationA.

I wonder what I need to do in order to invalidate the session when I try to get keycloak security context from the request... and not to wait for the time if gets invalidated.

**Update**

The problem is not on my code, its just that `AuthenticationApplication` cannot find `ApplicationA`. After adding `ApplicationA` to `/etc/hosts` of `AuthenticationApplication` it can now send `/k_logout` requests to `ApplicationA`.

There are no changes needed in `ApplicationA` and everything works.

Apology for thinking that the issue was on `ApplicationA`, the posted configuration works (depending on your application needs, but for me it works as expected).

I will not remove this post, maybe others will have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Super late answer, but what you were looking for is [Back-channel Logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-backchannel-1_0.html).

This was supported by Keycloak adapters for Spring at the time you wrote your question, but those were [deprecated in early 2022](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187).

You may refer to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571191/use-keycloak-spring-adapter-with-spring-boot-3/74572732#74572732) for migrating to Spring Security "official" Boot starter (with **optionally** an additional starter of mine).

Since recently, [Spring Security supports Back-channel Logout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/logout.html#configure-provider-initiated-oidc-logout). With that, you can have all clients be notified (and close their own session) when any other client logs out a user.

Answer (score -1):

I got a similar situation on my project.
I added an endpoint to refresh the token on initial page load.

You can call `context.refreshExpiredToken(false)` on your `RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext`. The `false` flag indicate to not check the current token validity and force the refresh from keycloak.

As the doc says:

> @return true if accessToken is active or was successfully refreshed

So if you get a `false` you know your user is not connected anymore.
You can add a `session.invalidate()` and `request.logout()` on failed refresh (I'm not sure if it's necessary).